# Cannot update profile picture

Tags: user-profile

Cannot update profile picture, trying to add a picture to profiles and I recieve the follwoing error. " There was an error saving the picture. Please try again later. "

Has this been resolved? if yes, How?

http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/11/07/admin-cannot-upload-profile-picture-after-sp1-and-june-cu.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was fixed in the [SharePoint Server 2010 cumulative update package for December 2011.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597014)

"An administrator cannot upload a user’s profile picture to Central Administration in SharePoint Server 2010. Additionally, the administrator receives the following error message:
There was an error saving the picture. Please try again later."